# Unable to create new account on Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I'm unable to create a new account on Parse.com, when I click create, the page just gets reloaded.
I'm aware that of the fact that Parse will be deprecated soon, but I didn't find any info on not taking on new accounts.

I tried to contact but get "Sorry, the link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed." Any thoughts/help on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to create anymore.

But you can keep using Parse. Parse Server community is growing and it is becoming even better than original Parse. In a short time, Parse Server will become the best framework for backend and API development.

My recommendation to you is to start using a Parse Hosting provider. Using this kind of solution you will use same Parse APIs and features. It will not require you learn other technology nor rewrite any frontend code.

You can find some options in parse server repository:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server#parse-server-sample-application

For a full disclaimer, I am co-founder of https://www.back4app.com

Answer (score 1):

I afraid that you cannot anymore create a new account In `Parse.com` since they will shut off their service on 28 January 2017.
The only things you can do are using the Parse Server open source solution (self-Hosted or commercial hosted) as it's explained in their migration guide. Or you can search for alternative solutions. One that looks promising is `"Back{4}app"` ; there are trying to reproduce the entire service offered by Parse.